# vsto and manifest files are not created from the command line

Tags: c#, vsto, manifest

I have 2 different old c# VSTO projects from VStudio 2010 for Excel add-ins.
Both projects are compiled in VStudio 2010 and create 4 files each: .dll, .pdb, .vsto, .manifest.
Both projects compile and create the specified files from the msbuild .Net 4.0 command line. ("C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe" ...)

The main product is compiled from command line by msbuild from BuidTools VisualStudio 2019 (msbuild2019) with the key /p:VisualStudioVersion="11.0" ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe" ... /p:VisualStudioVersion="11.0...")
One of the 2 projects is compiled from the msbuild2019 command line and creates the entire set of files.

The second project compiles from the msbuild2019 command line without errors BUT DOES NOT CREATE .vsto and .manifest files.

Where to look for the problem?

Analysis of diagnostic level logs from the msbuild40 and msbuild2019 compilations of the second problem project shows

- that VSToolsPath are different, as expected,
- The msbuild2019 log is missing at least the following fields:
  DeploymentManifestExtension
  DeploymentManifestFileName
  DeploymentManifestWithPath
  DeploymentManifestWithPathForPublishing
  DeploymentManifestWithPathPublished
  VSTO_DeploymentFileMappingExtension
  VSTO_ProjectType

ApplicationManifestFileNameCollection
ApplicationManifestWithPathCollection
...
/